# List of actuals import names in python

Tags: python, pip

With "pip freeze" I'll get a list of package  names. e.g.:

```
Django==1.9.7
psycopg2==2.6.1
djangorestframework==3.3.3
djangorestframework-jwt==1.8.0
django-rest-swagger==0.3.7
django-environ==0.4.0
python-dateutil==2.5.3
django-sendfile==0.3.10
```

Is there any way to receive a list of actual names to `import`? e.g. instead of `djangorestframework` => `rest_framework`

Comment: Try  `pip list`. This may be you looking for.

Comment: @RahulKP that gives you the package name, but *not* necessarily the thing you `import`.

Comment: Isn't it in name of the actual module stored in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages (windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, top_level.txt will be a correct module name. You can use pkg_resources module to extract metadata from packages.

Python code for this:

```
import pkg_resources


def read_requirements(requirements_file):
    with open(requirements_file, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()


def get_package_name(package):
    return list(pkg_resources.get_distribution(package)._get_metadata('top_level.txt'))[0]


requirements = read_requirements('/path/to/requirements.txt')
packages = [get_package_name(p) for p in requirements]
```

Answer (score 6):

You may use the standard [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) module to get the list of top-level imports like this:

```
import pkgutil
list(pkgutil.iter_modules())
```

That will only find modules that live in regular files, zip files or another loader that supports module enumration. Should be most of them on a standard system.

The result is a list of 3-tuple, with the loader, the module name, and whether it is a single module or a package. If you are only interested in the module name, simply do:

```
list(item[1] for item in pkgutil.iter_modules())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to look at the first line of this file :

```
# If output of pip freeze is djangorestframework==3.3.3
# Then your dir prefix becomes "djangorestframework-3.3.3"

../lib/python2.7/site-packages/<dir-prefix>.dist-info/top_level.txt 

# e.g.
../lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.3.3.dist-info/top_level.txt
```